# How to generate Key Hash for facebook SDK Mac

Tags: android, facebook, macos, key, android-facebook

i try to generate Key Hash for facebook SDK Mac.i searched and i found solution

keytool -exportcert -alias myalias -keystore myapk.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

and i recived keyhash and i inserted this keyhash my developerfacebook page.
but i have error invalid keyhash.
My appliacation  can use facebook sdk ,i can login facebook but,
i have error when divice use also facebook aplication.I have no ideaa what is i am doing wrong.
if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: Are your using facebook sdk for osx? What library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code in the onCreate method and obtain the Keyhash, place it in the keyhashes section. Hope it works

```
private void getKeyHash(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.android", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("Obtained KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
    }
```